# Invert matrix numbers - loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

First, i have these values.

```
$Arr1 = array(1/1, 1/2, 3/1);
$Arr2 = array(1/1, 4/1);
$Arr3 = array(1/1);
```

and i need an output with 3 arrays like these:

```
$a1 = array (1/1, 1/2, 3/1);
$a2 = array (2/1, 1/1, 4/1);
$a3 = array (1/3, 1/4, 1,1);
```

What i am trying is :

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($Arr1); $i++) {
    ${"a".$i} = array(
        //here, the number of array elements depends to the length of $a1
    );
}
```

Any help ? thanks

I think this image helps to understand the problem:

[image]

Comment: what kind of function / transformation are you using to get the output arrays? how does $a map to $a1?

Comment: @bryan i don't have any output for now. The loop that i can't make, is supposed produce in this case, 4 arrays.

Comment: I understand that, but I'm asking how do you compute the values of the new arrays? Like... what is the formula? For example "Multiply every element in $a by 3 and add 6" or something like that. Do you understand my question? Given $a, how do you produce $a1?

Comment: There is no calculations. For example, $Arr4 corresponds to $a4.

Comment: Okay that's clear but how do those negative values appear, I think that's what Brian is asking?

Comment: i think that is more easy if i edit my question. I will use the same values of the images for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, using a 2D array will make your life a lot easier.

So first, initialize your values like this:

```
$matrix_size = 3;
$matrix = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $matrix_size; $i++){
    $matrix[$i] = array_fill(0, $matrix_size, null);
}

$matrix[0][0] = 1/1; 
$matrix[0][1] = 1/2; 
$matrix[0][2] = 3/1; 

$matrix[1][1] = 1/1; 
$matrix[1][2] = 4/1; 

$matrix[2][2] = 1/1;
```

Then you can run a loop like this:

```
foreach($x = 0; $x < $matrix_size; $x++){
    foreach($y = 0; $y < $matrix_size; $y++){
        if(is_null($matrix[y][x]) && !is_null($matrix[x][y])){
            $matrix[y][x] = 1/$matrix[x][y];
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure there is a much more efficient way to do this, but this is a start for you to explore.

Comment: sorry about the editing in my question, but i think now it is more clearly for all.